# Modify items in Opportunity page - Status field

Tags: acumatica

I have been able to modify the dropdown values for other fields in the Opportunity page like Stage and Source, and even the Status field in other pages like Leads

The CROpportunity.Status column is defined as

```
public abstract class status : PX.Data.IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXStringList(new string[0], new string[0])]
    [PXMassUpdatableField]
    [PXDefault()]
    public virtual string Status { get; set; }enter code here
```

There is no LeadStatuses attribute to be replaced.

In the Contact DAC, the column is defined in the following way

```
#region Status
    public abstract class status : IBqlField { }
    [PXDBString(1, IsFixed = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Status")]
    [LeadStatuses]
    public virtual String Status { get; set; }
    #endregionenter code here
```

It is, therefore possible to substitute the LeadStatuses attribute with a CacheExtension for the Contact DAC, or a GraphExtension over LeadMaint. But it's not the case for the CROpportunity DAC or the OpportunityMaint graph.

Any ideas?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Following @Philippe suggestion, I was able to rename an existing status. "New" to "Newest"

However, when I try to create a new Automation Step. Reviewing the Combo Box values smartpanel, doesn't show the option to add new values:
[Combo box values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65ajn.png)

I reviewed the AU tables but couldn't find any where these statuses values are stored - it would seem to be handled in the BLC layer

**UPDATE 2**
The option to add new values can be obtained by right-clicking on the grid
[Combo box values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLgHJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statuses in Opportunities and Leads are defined in the Automation Steps. I covered a part of how automation steps can define business logic in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31860648/1038954) that could be helpful to you.

The basics here are as follow: Documents can have "workflows/steps" where some actions and fields are only available if they are in a specified step. Those steps are configurable without customization and thus can have status that are manage without customization as well. For more information about Automation Steps, I would refer you to the Help under Help > User Guide > Automation > Overview > Workflow Customization by Means of Automation Steps

[image: Automation Steps - Statuses]

Comment: thanks for the reply @Philippe. Please find my updated original post with follow up questions.

Comment: Philippe, an updated version solving the follow up question has been posted. Thanks!

Comment: @BillBlake, Yes sorry I didn't see your comment... Double clicking on the grid would add an additionnal row too... The delete key should delete an existing one as well. Glad you solved your issue.